# Airflow DAG scheduler loop generating high costs on Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, azure-data-factory

Our Airflow DAG is generating very high costs on ADF.

The Airflow scheduler constantly loops to check if the DAG has changed. In this log we find the list of ADF pipelines. Each time the DAG is checked for changes (> 3 times a minute) the list of ADF pipelines is queried.

Here's the log items that are repeated througout the day:

```
[2021-05-10 00:00:06,032] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-05-10 00:00:06,031] {{settings.py:253}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=29572
[2021-05-10 00:00:06,035] {{scheduler_job.py:153}} INFO - Started process (PID=29572) to work on /usr/local/airflow/dags/ingestSource.py
[2021-05-10 00:00:06,038] {{scheduler_job.py:1560}} INFO - Processing file /usr/local/airflow/dags/ingestSource.py for tasks to queue
[2021-05-10 00:00:06,038] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-05-10 00:00:06,038] {{dagbag.py:403}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/ingestSource.py
[2021-05-10 00:00:07,395] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Existing data factory pipelines: ['Load Facts', 'Refresh Report', 'Post Staging Logic', 'Load Dimensions', 'etc..']
[2021-05-10 00:00:08,000] {{scheduler_job.py:161}} INFO - Processing /usr/local/airflow/dags/ingestSource.py took 1.965 seconds
```

This part of the DAG seems to trigger the query on ADF:

```
azure_data_factory_hook = AzureDataFactoryHook(
    subscription_id=os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"],
    resource_group_name=os.environ["AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME"],
    factory_name=os.environ["AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_NAME"],
    credentials=MSIAuthentication() 
)
```

I would really like to know why the query to ADF gets triggered and how prevent this from happening in a loop whole day long.

Thanks for your help

The full DAG:

```
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Dict, List

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.azure_data_factory_plugin import AzureDataFactoryHook
from airflow.operators.azure_data_factory_plugin import AdfPipelineRunOperator
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'Me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(hours=6)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id="IngestSource",
          start_date=datetime(2020, 5, 29),
          default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
          max_active_runs=5,
          schedule_interval='0 1 * * *')

azure_data_factory_hook = AzureDataFactoryHook(
    subscription_id=os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"],
    resource_group_name=os.environ["AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME"],
    factory_name=os.environ["AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_NAME"],
    credentials=MSIAuthentication() 
)

common_task_params = {
    "dag": dag,
    "azureDataFactoryHook": azure_data_factory_hook,
    "execution_timeout": timedelta(hours=2),
}

ingest_source = AdfPipelineRunOperator(
    **common_task_params,
    task_id="ingestSource",
    pipeline_name="From Source to Target",
    pipeline_parameters=json.dumps()
)
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what's exactly going on without seeing the logic in the custom Hook and Operator. Typically Hooks are used within Operators as Operators are the typical interface within DAGs. Any context around that logging statement would be useful as well.

Comment: Hi @JoshFell, thank you for your comments, I've added the full log that is generated by the scheduler, hope it gives more insight

Answer (score 1):

Presumably there is something in the Hook that retrieves the existing ADF pipelines to write out in the log. This Hook is considered top-level code (any function, logic, etc. that is outside of an Operator's `execute()` method) and it is considered best practice to avoid in a DAG file.  Top-level code is executed upon each file parse interval of the Scheduler -- hence the frequent query you are noticing.  You should try moving the Hook into your custom Operator within the scope of the `execute()` method.